# SPSS : run ARIMA modeling through script

Tags: data-mining, spss, forecasting

I know that it is possible to perform various functions of SPSS through scripts.

Is it also possible to run ARIMA modeling through scripts? If yes, are there any good tutorials/documents for that?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The software R should be your choice.

Does this help you?

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/arima.html

Comment: Sir, I am aware of R. But I found some differences in forecasts by SPSS and R. And rest of my team is using SPSS. So that might create some problems.

Comment: Well from your question, it was not clear whether you wanted to stay with SPSS or not. In fact, now that I read your question, it's not clear at all :)

Comment: Do you want something like this ? http://www.opf.slu.cz/vvr/akce/turecko/pdf/Kocurkova.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Anything computational that you can do via the user interface in SPSS can also be done using syntax.  In particular, the ARIMA command does those models.  Many users prefer, instead, to use the Expert Modeler in Statistics, which automates much of the process of figuring out the appropriate ARIMA model, stationarity transformations, outlier handling, etc.  That is the TSMODEL command.  Since virtually every dialog box in Statistics has a Paste button that generates the syntax and places it in the Syntax Editor window, it is easy to build a syntax file by doing point and click.

Statistics also supports scripting via the Python, .NET, Basic, and even R languages.

Take a look at the Case Studies on the Help menu for quick walkthroughs on forecasting as well as other statisticall topi